# Solve the separable differential equation $ {dy\over dx}=2x\sqrt{1-y^2}, -1<y<1 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the separable differential equation:

$ {dy\over dx}=2x\sqrt{1-y^2}, -1<y<1 $

I understand the process of finding the solution, but I am getting the answer $C=\sin^{-1}y-x^2 $. The book says the answer is $y=\sin(x^2+C)$. I just don't understand how to convert my answer into $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you follow these steps?
$$
C=\sin^{-1}(y)-x^2\\
x^2+C=\sin^{-1}(y)\\
\sin(x^2+C)=y
$$

Comment: But what I don't understand is how to $sin^{-1}y $ becomes $y=sin(x^2+C)$

Comment: $\sin^{-1}$ is _defined_ to be the function that works out that way: $$a=\sin^{-1}(b)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \sin(a)=b$$ (within certain limitations).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\int 2xdx$$
Let $y=\sin\theta$
$$\int\frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{\cos\theta}=x^2+C$$
$$\theta=\sin^{-1}y=x^2+C$$
$$y=\sin(x^2+C)$$